# On form submit determine which submit button action is clicked

Tags: backbone.js

How can I get the 'Submit button action' when a form is submitted? For example;

```
<form data-action="foo">

  <button type="submit" name="action" value="update">Update</button>
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

In my Backbone View I am trying to figure which button was clicked:

```
,   events: {
        'submit form[data-action="foo"]': 'editSubscription'
    }

,   editSubscription: function(e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        // How can I determine the submit action is 'update' or 'cancel'

        // Save the model, ie, implicitly do a POST with action UPDATE or CANCEL
        this.model.save({action: 'update' /*or 'cancel'*/}, ...);
    }
```

Comment: `event.target` will help you.

Comment: Why do you set `type="submit"`  and trigger form submission on a cancel button?

Answer (score 0):

By getting value of submit button.

```
$(document).on("click", ":submit", function(e){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in Vanilla JS in the following way:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button[type=submit]').forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log('You have clicked the button:', this.value);
    e.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

```html
<form data-action="foo">

  <button type="submit" name="action" value="update">Update</button>
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

**OR:** If you prefer jQuery:

```js
$('button[type=submit]').on('click', function(e){
  console.log('You have clicked the button:', this.value);
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form data-action="foo">

  <button type="submit" id="update" name="action" value="update">Update</button>
  <button type="submit" id="cancel" name="action" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the button value on click event, use prevent default to stop form submit

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll('button');
el.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(e.target.value);  
    })
})
```

```html
<form data-action="foo">
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="update">Update</button>
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get notification. Just add `id` attribute to element and get it from  [currentTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/).

```js
var eventType = '';
$("button").on("click",function(e){
  alert($(e.currentTarget).attr('id')+' clicked');
  eventType = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id');
  //this.model.save({action: eventType}, ...);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form data-action="foo">

  <button type="submit" id="update" name="action" value="update">Update</button>
  <button type="submit" id="cancel" name="action" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The simplest way is by using `event.target` you can get the `value` of button and put the condition on that**

```
    // you can determine by e.target.value that action is 'update' or 'cancel'
   if(e.target.value=='update'){
          // Save the model, ie, implicitly do a POST with action UPDATE
           this.model.save({action: 'update'}, ...);
   }
   if(e.target.value=='cancel'){
      // Save the model, ie, implicitly do a POST with action CANCEL
       this.model.save({action: 'cancel'}, ...);
   }
```

**Your updated code:**

```
 ,   events: {
            'submit form[data-action="foo"]': 'editSubscription'
        }

    ,   editSubscription: function(e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            // you can determine by e.target.value that action is 'update' or 'cancel'
            if(e.target.value=='update'){
            // Save the model, ie, implicitly do a POST with action UPDATE
            this.model.save({action: 'update'}, ...);
            }
            if(e.target.value=='cancel'){
            // Save the model, ie, implicitly do a POST with action CANCEL
            this.model.save({action: 'cancel'}, ...);
            }

        }
```